# Android Drag and DRop Auto Scroll

Tags: c#, xamarin, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to figure out how to auto scroll a scrollview when a user drags an item to the edge of the screen. I'm really not getting the behavious I expect out of this code. Does anyone have an example or a technique that works?

I have this in my:

```
onDrag(View v, DragEvent e)
{
   case DragAction.Location:

    var currentPosition = (int)e.GetX();

    var point = GetTouchPositionFromDragEvent(v, e);

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"DragAction.Location from {v.GetType()} => {currentPosition}");
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine($"DragAction.GLOBAL   from {v.GetType()} => {point.X}");

    if (point.X > App.AppScreenWidth - 50)
    {
        _hostScrollView.ScrollToAsync(_hostScrollView.ScrollX + 30, 0, true);
    }

    if (point.X < 50)
    {
        _hostScrollView.ScrollToAsync(_hostScrollView.ScrollX - 30, 0, true);
    }    
}

public static Point GetTouchPositionFromDragEvent(View item, DragEvent e) 
{
    Rect rItem = new Rect();
    item.GetGlobalVisibleRect(rItem);
    return new Point(rItem.Left + (int)Math.Round(e.GetX()), rItem.Top + (int)Math.Round(e.GetY()));
}
```

This also has the knock on effect of only scrolling in one direction strangely and also requires the user to keep moving the item in order to fire the events which leads me to think this is entirely the wrong place to be even trying to do this scrolling.

Any pointers or nudges in the right direction would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### In your Activity

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity, View.IOnDragListener,View.IOnScrollChangeListener
```

```
private int mScrollDistance;
```

```
 ScrollView _hostScrollView= FindViewById<ScrollView>(Resource.Id.xxx);
_hostScrollView.SetOnScrollChangeListener(this);
```

```
public bool OnDrag(View v, DragEvent e)
        {
            var action = e.Action;

            var scrollView = v as ScrollView;

            switch (action)
            {
                case DragAction.Started:

                    break;
                case DragAction.Location:
                    
                        int y = Java.Lang.Math.Round(e.GetY());
                        int translatedY = y - mScrollDistance;
                        int threshold = 50;
                        // make a scrolling up due the y has passed the threshold
                        if (translatedY < threshold)
                        {
                            // make a scroll up by 30 px
                            scrollView.ScrollBy(0, -30);
                        }
                        // make a autoscrolling down due y has passed the 500 px border
                        if (translatedY + threshold > 500)
                        {
                            // make a scroll down by 30 px
                            scrollView.ScrollBy(0, 30);
                        }
                   
                    break;
                    
            }
            return true;
        }

        public void OnScrollChange(View v, int scrollX, int scrollY, int oldScrollX, int oldScrollY)
        {
            var scrollView = v as ScrollView;
            mScrollDistance = scrollView.ScrollY;
        }
```

You could modify the logic as you want if I misunderstand your requirement .

Comment: Would this work in an Adapter class? As I@m doing this in Xamarin Forms.

Comment: Also the `var scrollView = v as ScrollView;` is that a Xamarin ScrollView or an Android one?

Comment: Ohh, My Code is for xamarin.Android . Since you work in Xamarin.Forms , why you have an Adapter class ?

Comment: You could provide the full code in xaml and code behind .

Comment: The adaptor is in a custom renderer as I have a pretty complex UI to build.

Comment: I should still be able to use this code in my adapter, I'm just looking at trying it now.

Comment: Yes!  My code is just a demo for you . It works in my native project and you should modify it as you need .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215101/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-jammer).

Comment: @Lucas Zhang - MSFT, please tell how to work with xamarin form scrolling problem